# Why MediaElement doesnot work on call-time?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some MediaElements in my WPF-application

If i call `Question1_5.Play();` then `Timer_activated.Play();` does not play on time (this audio plays 5-6 seconds after calling Play() method).

What the problem?

```
        private void NewGame_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, 
        MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => Windows.SelectedItem = Game));
        Questions1_5.Play();
        sb = FindResource("TimerAppear") as Storyboard;
        sb.Begin();
        sb.Pause();
        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 4);
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Timer_activated.Play();
        sb.Resume();
        sb = FindResource("Seconds15") as Storyboard;
        timer.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, i'm from Russia and know english badly.

I tried using async await, and it ended up being an exception.
I tried to run 2 tunes at the same time in the same method - the outcome has not changed. I tried to move these MediaElements to different places in XAML - it didn't help. If you first start Timer_activated, and then Questions1_5 - everything will be OK, but that I don't generally best.

Comment: try :Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => Questions1_5.Play()), DispatcherPriority.Background); instead of Questions1_5.Play()

Comment: I have tried, but It's doesn't help me =(

Comment: Timer_activated.Play() will be played after 6-7 seconds, not before. How to disable it?

Comment: I need start my mediaelement in any moment, not when it will take 6-7 seconds